# Enabled FileVault with disabled SSV possible with Big Sur?

Tags: filevault, big-sur, macos

My Hardware is a 2019 MacBook Pro 15" has the T2 chip and runs macOS 11.0.1.

After disabling SSV via `csrutil authenticated-root disable` and rebooting I can not enable FileVault. Unfortunately the error is very generic: "FileVault Failed An internal error has occurred."

Is it possible to have signed system volume (SSV) disabled but FileVault enabled?

Comment: My hunch is you lose everything when you disable everything with that command but we will surely test this a bit down the line when we evaluate BS security at work (lol) - the guide usually updates each spring - https://support.apple.com/guide/security/welcome/web

Comment: My understanding is that you have to have Filevault off to disable SSV. Can't help much more, as I haven't read much into the new SSV feature.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to user experiences - this is not possible.
Disabling SSV will leave the system stripped out of  both SIP and File Vault.

https://eclecticlight.co/2020/06/25/big-surs-signed-system-volume-added-security-protection/#comments

Comment: I've also heard (but can't confirm), that disabling SSV prevents you from using Apple Pay as well.

Comment: Yes, not just ApplePay but all protected features.On M1 Macs - it will disable all iOS (iphone/iPad) apps...

Comment: Interesting, didn't know that @Belter. Also welcome to Ask Different :)